# Why device applications should be packaged?

Tags: vb.net, packaging, cab, smart-device

Why should be device applications packaged like described here :

[Packaging Device Solutions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz5xy1zx(v=vs.90).aspx)

I could copy the exe file in to the file system of my mdt and start it from there.
Everything works. So why the packeging into the cab files???

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(file_format)) (device) is essentially the same as [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (windows), they are both used for the installation of software (applications).

I think the real question here is:

> **What is an installer?**

To quote wikipedia:

**Common operations performed during software installations include**

- Making sure that necessary system requirements are met
- Checking for existing versions of the software
- Creating or updating program files and folders
- Adding configuration data such as configuration files, Windows registry entries or environment variables
- Making the software accessible to the user, for instance by creating links, shortcuts or bookmarks
- Configuring components that run automatically, such as daemons or Windows services
- Performing product activation
- Updating the software versions

*Read more about installation (computer programs) at wikipedia:*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_(computer_programs)